# deprecated unity networking system

Tags: unity, networking

I have pretty old half done unity multiplayer project. I made it with the old unity multiplayer system that now has deprecated.

now can I complete it with the old unity network? or i need to learn new networking system?

Comment: If people are going to downvote, at least flag it?

Comment: @Ryanwhite Can you describe why people should flag a post if they're going to downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on if your migrating to the new engine? if you are then you may encounter some problems, as i did. But that being said it is dependent on how your doing. The old unity networking was built on a client side server hosting - The idea that, during testing, you would host client side i.e the player hosts. This is still sort of the case now, but unity offer hosting etc, for no fee up to 100 users at one time *I think*

> (For new projects, you should use the new networking system introduced
>   in 5.1. This information is for legacy projects using the old
>   networking system.)

this is from unity's website regarding the legacy networking, they do advise against using the old system if your going to use the new engine.

*To sum it up*

Yes and no, but yes being the harder route, and no being the easier one (Learning the new networking)

If your going to use the new unity networking, most of it is done in similar ways, if not the same. Unity just has built in modules now to help, so its not so bad i guess.

although this is going to be very opinion based, and i expect downvotes, i want to help :)

Comment: Regarding the user limit on Unity's hosting service: According to [the store page](https://store.unity.com/), it's 20 for personal edition, 50 for plus, 200 for pro and a matter of negotiation for enterprise. When you have more players, you pay $0.45 per GB of traffic.

Comment: Ah, they must have changed it since the beta phase then, my account is still showing 100 users, i just assumed it had stayed that way my bad.

Comment: Im glad i could help you :)

Comment: @Ryan white thanks, i have another little question that i think its better to ask here: in old unity network system i always used my own server just by compile and upload "master server" to my server and... my question is that can i use my own server in this new network system just like i did befor?? or i just can use the unity's expensive server??

Comment: From my experience i believe you need to use there very expensive hosting. Another option could be to use PUN, Photon Unity Networking. They offer a free package that is a little better than UN, but it can be difficult to use and learn. And it can get costly.

Comment: @Ryanwhite no no no I have situation... beside I always used my own server and I want also use my own server in my next projects... (I calculated and I figur out that using my own server will be very cheaper that those photon or unet services (specially for +1-3k ccu)... any way my question is that can I easily use my own server in this new networking system right? thanks

Comment: I believe you can, the new system should still allow it. You would have to test it though, as i cant be 100% sure.

Comment: @Ryanwhite ok i will. and i will commend result here.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general, changing technology mid-way in a far progressed project is usually more costly than it is worth. It's not just the work of replacing those parts which directly interact with the technology. It's also the cost of learning the technology, learning to use it *well* (which is usually easier on a green-field project where you have less moving parts around it) and fixing all the *indirect* dependencies on the old technology (parts of your overall software architecture which were designed around the old technology handling specific things in specific ways, even though they appear quite far away from it). So we developers tend to grossly underestimate the short-term and long-term cost of such a move. Usually it is the more economical decision to just finish the project the way we started.

But on the other hand, introducing new technology can sometimes solve some as of yet unsolved problems in your project.

So my recommendation would be to teach yourself what the new technology has to offer. Then see if there is anything which solves a problem you haven't solved yet and is easier to do than with the old technology.

When your multiplayer system is already working well and your game just needs some polish in other areas, stay with what you have and focus on getting it shipped. But when your multiplayer system is still just partly done, buggy, slow and generally makes you feel miserable when you look at it, trashing it and redoing it from scratch with the new technology *might* give a payoff.

Just remember the old wisdom in software development: When it sounds easy to do, you aren't aware of all the details yet.